# Acess belongsTo by where

Tags: json, laravel

I got this code:

```
public function Locate($name){
    $locate= Products::where('name', 'like', "$name%") ->get();

    return response()->json($locate, 200);
}
```

I want to access belongsTo by this $name and put it in json

Here is my model:

```
class Products extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'code', 'price'];

    protected $hidden = ['id'];

    public function Group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\pGroup', 'product_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a relationship :

`$locate= Products::where('name', 'like', "$name%")->with('group')->get();`

Comment: There is. I got one another question. Is there a way to access the foreign key inside this relashionp and return in json? If i use your code, the json return all group, but with foreign key numbers